# Unity - deleting a specific gameobject when mouse/pointer is over it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a virtual reality game where when you double click on an object it deletes it. However multiple objects are duplicates of eachother so when i attach my double click script to them it will delete all the objects upon double click. I want it to just delete the one the mouse is on. I will attach my script below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class doubleClick : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float firstClickTime, timebetweenClicks;
    private bool coroutineAllowed;
    private int clickCounter;
    public GameObject toDelete;
   

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        firstClickTime = 0f;
        timebetweenClicks = 0.2f;
        clickCounter = 0;
        coroutineAllowed = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
            clickCounter += 1;

        if (clickCounter == 1 && coroutineAllowed)
        {
            firstClickTime = Time.time;
            StartCoroutine(DoubleClickDetection());
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator DoubleClickDetection()
    {
        coroutineAllowed = false;
        while (Time.time < firstClickTime + timebetweenClicks)
        {
           
            if (clickCounter == 2)
                {
                    //Destroy(toDelete);
                    break;
                }
                yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();           
        }
        clickCounter = 0;
        firstClickTime = 0f;
        coroutineAllowed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have deleted the tag [tag:UnityScript] and added [tag:C#] from your question as this question is about C# and not UnityScript. Please note that UnityScript is its own (deprecated) scripting language and not a blanket tag for any kind of script in Unity (as explained in the tag information)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything that jumps out in your code. Padia's answer is on the right track, though. Mouse input handling when you want to interact with objects is best done from within that object/prefab. That way, you're guaranteed that only that object is interacted with. If not, then there's likely something else going on with your code.

Unfortunately, it's a little late for me to work out a complete solution. But here's a possible solution.

1. Within the prefab's code, insert an OnMouseDown function. In that function, check if the double-click timer's been started. If not, set a flag to tell the prefab that the double-click timer needs to start (call it WaitingForTimerStart). You could alternatively use an enum to hold the timer state. In any event, don't start the timer yet.
2. Within the prefab's code, insert an OnMouseUp function. That should check if the timer start flag's (WaitingForTimerStart) been set. If it has, set another timer flag to tell it to run the timer (RunTimer).
3. In the prefab's Update function, run the timer. I'm sure you know what to do here.
4. In the prefab's OnMouseDown function (the one you added earlier), check if the timer's running. If it is, then you know a double-click's been performed. Destroy the object.

This way, there's no need to check names, use raycasting or coroutines. Each object will have its own timer and be fully independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

One main issue with your code is: You are starting the Coroutine **everyframe**!

You have to wrap your code block in `{ }` after the `if`, otherwise the condition only applies for the one line after it!

Instead of

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    clickCounter += 1;

if (clickCounter == 1 && coroutineAllowed)
{
    firstClickTime = Time.time;
    StartCoroutine(DoubleClickDetection());
}
```

it should probably rather be

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
{
    clickCounter += 1;

    if (clickCounter == 1 && coroutineAllowed)
    {
        firstClickTime = Time.time;
        StartCoroutine(DoubleClickDetection());
    }
}
```

---

Then

> I want it to just delete the one the mouse is on.

Well currently you are using `Input.GetMouseButtonUp` which is true **global** in the entire app, not only the object the mouse is currently over.

You can rather use e.g. [`OnMouseDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html) which is called when the mouse goes down over a collider or UI element.

```
private void OnMouseDown ()
{
    clickCounter += 1;

    if (clickCounter == 1 && coroutineAllowed)
    {
        firstClickTime = Time.time;
        StartCoroutine(DoubleClickDetection());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
    private float firstClickTime, timebetweenClicks;
    private bool coroutineAllowed;
    private int clickCounter;
    RaycastHit hit;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        firstClickTime = 0f;
        timebetweenClicks = 0.2f;
        clickCounter = 0;
        coroutineAllowed = true;
    }

    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        clickCounter += 1;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (clickCounter == 1 && coroutineAllowed)
        {
            firstClickTime = Time.time;
            StartCoroutine(DoubleClickDetection());
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator DoubleClickDetection()
    {
        coroutineAllowed = false;
        while (Time.time < firstClickTime + timebetweenClicks)
        {

            if (clickCounter == 2)
            {
                if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit))
                {
                    if (hit.collider.transform == this.transform)
                    {
                        Destroy(this.gameObject);
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        }
        clickCounter = 0;
        firstClickTime = 0f;
        coroutineAllowed = true;
    }
```

This code use OnMouseDown() Unity function to detect when the game object is clicked by the mouse, and add 1 to the clickCounter variable.
Also you can use OnMouseUp() function if you prefer to detect the click when the mouse is up.

Comment: Thank you, however my problem is that multiple gameObjects have the same name. so for example if the gameobject i want to delete is a coin, but i have 10 duplicates of coin, when i double click on coin, all coins delete. I think what i need to fix this is an if statement that says (if the mouse is over the gameobject delete it) but I cannot find how to code this.

Comment: Thanks again, but same problem, all duplicated gameObjects are deleted instead of just the one im clicking on

Comment: Are your game objects parent of another game object?

Comment: Basically i have two prefabs, when i click on one it spawns the other into the game. So the second prefab is the one that keeps on spawning into the game.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the hierarchy structure?

Comment: Okay imagine you have gameObject and gameObject1. gameObject1 is a prefab, gameObject is displayed in the hierarchy and in the game but gameObject1 is not. When a user is playing the game they will see gameObject on the screen. When the click on it, it will appear to duplicate, spawning gameObject1 to screen. Then if they wish to delete gameObject1 they need to double click on it. This is where the problem arises as all the gameObject1's delete instead of just the one they are clicking on

Comment: I have added a Raycast that checks if mouse is over the object, it should work now

Comment: Thanks again for all your help. Unfortunately this still deletes all the gameObject1 duplicates at the same time